# checking network connection when application in taskmanager

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking

I to create one application and I want to check network connection when application is running 
or any time run application first check network connection (I need check network if this application to be in task manager and then run)

I dont know about it .

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [Reachability example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple code samples.

Basically, you can import the `Reachability.h` and `Reachability.m` in your project and then use the available methods for checking the network state.